# python, plot planck curves looping through arrays

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I try to get myself familiar with programming in python but have just started and struggling with the following problem. Maybe someone can give me a hint how to proceed or where I can look for a nice solution.

I'd like to plot planck curves for 132 wavelength in 6 different temperatures via a loop in a loop. The function planckwavel receives two parameters, wavelength and temperature, which I separated in two loops.

I so far managed to use lists, which worked, however probably not solved in an elegant way:

```
plancks = []
temp = [280, 300, 320, 340, 360, 380]
temp_len = len(temp)

### via fun planckwavel
for i in range(temp_len):
    t_list = [] # list nach jeder j schleife wieder leeren
    for j in range(wl_centers_ar.shape[0]):
        t = planckwavel(wl_centers_ar[j],temp[i])
        t_list.append(t)      
    plancks.append(t_list)


### PLOT Planck curves

plancks = np.array(plancks).T # convert list to array and transpose

view_7 = plt.figure(figsize=(8.5, 4.5))
plt.plot(wl_centers_ar,plancks)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
```

But I would like to use arrays insted of lists, as I like to continue afterwards with huge more dimensional images. So I tried the same with arrays but unfortunately failed with this code:

```
plancks_ar = zeros([132,6], dtype=float ) # create array and fill with zeros
temp_ar = array([273, 300, 310, 320, 350, 373])

for i in range(temp_ar.shape[0]):
    t_ar = np.zeros(plancks_ar.shape[0])
    for j in range(plancks_ar.shape[0]):
        t = planck(wl_centers_ar[j]*1e-6,temp[1])/10**6
        np.append(t_ar,t)        
    np.append(plancks_ar, t_ar)

plt.plot(wl_centers_ar,plancks)
```

I would be very thankful, if someone can give me some advice.

Thanx,
best regards,

peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking about how to use NumPy's [broadcasting and vectorization](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Here's a way to remove the explicit Python loops:

```
import numpy as np

# Some physical constants we'll need
h, kB, c = 6.626e-34, 1.381e-23, 2.998e8

def planck(lam, T):
    # The Planck function, using NumPy vectorization
    return 2*h*c**2/lam**5 / (np.exp(h*c/lam/kB/T) - 1)

# wavelength array, 3 - 300 um
lam = np.linspace(3, 75, 132)
# temperature array
T = np.array([280, 300, 320, 340, 360, 380])
# Remember to convert wavelength from um to m
pfuncs = planck(lam * 1.e-6, T[:,None])

import pylab
for pfunc in pfuncs:
    pylab.plot(lam, pfunc)
pylab.show()
```

[image]

We want to calculate `planck` for each wavelength and for each T, so we need to broadcast the calculation over the two arrays. Following the rules laid out in the documentation linked to above, we can do that by adding a new axis to the temperature array (with `T[:, None]`):

```
lam:       132
T      6 x   1
--------------
       6 x 132
```

The final dimension of `T[:, None]` is 1, so the 132 values of `lam` can be broadcast across it to produce a `6 x 132` array: 6 rows (one for each T) of 132 values (the wavelengths).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to doublecheck the above planck equation using the inverse (brightness temperature). Oriented on your code I definde the following function and expected to get 300 Kelvin (@ 10 microns, for 10 W/m2/str/microns):

```
def planckInv(lam, rad): 
     rad=rad*1.e6 #convert to W/m^2/m/sr 
     lam=lam*1.e-6 #convert wavelength to m 
     return (h*c/kB*lam)*( 1/ np.log( (2*h*c**2/lam**5) / rad +1 ))
```

but received a strange result

`planckInv(10,10)` - - > 3.0039933569668916e-08

Any suggestions what's wrong with my brightness temperature function?

thanks, 
peter

Comment: This really belongs as a separate question, but since it's unlikely to get answered on stackoverlow(!), the short answer is that your rearranged equation is wrong: the last line should be `return (h*c/kB/lam)*( 1/ np.log( (2*h*c**2/lam**5) / rad +1 ))`